# want to find Pivot value in pine script divergence indicator

Tags: pine-script

want to find two pivot value and need to insert into variable to use later.
i think if use array this can resolove but i feel difficulty .
anyone help me much appreciate!

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator("want to find divergence 2 pivot low value")

rangeUpper = input(title='Max of Lookback Range', defval=60)
rangeLower = input(title='Min of Lookback Range', defval=5)


rsi  = ta.rsi(close, 5)
plot(rsi, title="RSI", linewidth=2, color=#8D1699)
plotBull = input(title='Plot Bullish', defval=true)
plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(rsi, 2, 2)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(rsi, 2, 2)) ? false : true
_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish
// Osc: Higher Low

oscHL = rsi[2] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, rsi[2], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low

priceLL = low[2] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[2], 1)
bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

pltest = ta.pivotlow(rsi, 2, 2)

// want to insert two pivot value into variable.
firstPivotValue = ""
secondPivotValue = ""

plot(plFound ? rsi[2] : na, offset=-2, title='Regular Bullish', linewidth=2, color=bullCond ? color.green : color.gray)

plotshape(bullCond ? rsi[2] : na, offset=-2, title='Regular Bullish Label', text=' Bull ', style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the extreme points of your Bull divergence when :

Then you can store those values in a matrix, so that you can retrieve them easily : on row contains the two extremes point of your Bull divergence.

At the end of this code, there is a loop for testing purpose to verify that the stored values are the good : it reads the values in the matrix and place label with `F` for the first point and `S` for the second point of your Bull divergence.

[image]

The pinescript code :

```
//@version=5
indicator("want to find divergence 2 pivot low value")

rangeUpper = input(title='Max of Lookback Range', defval=60)
rangeLower = input(title='Min of Lookback Range', defval=5)


rsi  = ta.rsi(close, 5)
plot(rsi, title="RSI", linewidth=2, color=#8D1699)
plotBull = input(title='Plot Bullish', defval=true)
plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(rsi, 2, 2)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(rsi, 2, 2)) ? false : true
_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish
// Osc: Higher Low

oscHL = rsi[2] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, rsi[2], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low

priceLL = low[2] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[2], 1)
bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

pltest = ta.pivotlow(rsi, 2, 2)

// want to insert two pivot value into variable.
firstPivotValue = ""
secondPivotValue = ""

plot(plFound ? rsi[2] : na, offset=-2, title='Regular Bullish', linewidth=2, color=bullCond ? color.green : color.red)

plotshape(bullCond ? rsi[2] : na, offset=-2, title='Regular Bullish Label', text=' Bull ', style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

var MyDivValue = matrix.new<float>(0, 4, na)
// Create a matrix for : Bar_Index_First_Value, First_value, Bar_index_Second_Value, Second_value
// to store the value of Bull divergence 
//
// Store the Second point
if plFound and not(plFound[1]) and bullCond
    First_Value = rsi[2]
    // Create a new row in the matrix
    matrix.add_row(MyDivValue)
    // Add the Second Value to the last Row of the matrix
    matrix.set(MyDivValue, matrix.rows(MyDivValue) -1, 3, First_Value)
    // Add the bar index of the Second value
    matrix.set(MyDivValue, matrix.rows(MyDivValue) -1, 2, bar_index-3)

// Store the First point
if not(plFound) and plFound[1] and not(bullCond)
    Second_Value = rsi[2]
    if matrix.rows(MyDivValue) > 0
        // Add the Firts Value to the last Row of the matrix
        matrix.set(MyDivValue, matrix.rows(MyDivValue) -1, 1, Second_Value)
        // Add the bar index of the First value
        matrix.set(MyDivValue, matrix.rows(MyDivValue) -1, 0, bar_index-3)
if matrix.rows(MyDivValue) > 0
    for i = 0 to matrix.rows(MyDivValue)-1
        if bar_index - matrix.get(MyDivValue, i, 0) < 1000
            label.new(int(matrix.get(MyDivValue, i, 0)), matrix.get(MyDivValue, i, 1), "F")
            label.new(int(matrix.get(MyDivValue, i, 2)), matrix.get(MyDivValue, i, 3), "S")
```

Comment: thanks much! but sometimes it only printing F F not F S so i added this code to check whether S value is exist or not but also it not working. if bar_index - matrix.get(MyDivValue, i, 0) < 1000 and not na(matrix.get(MyDivValue, i, 2) and not na(matrix.get(MyDivValue, i, 3))) .